# Жестко ограничить форматы загружаемых файлов в <Input type="file">

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, input

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно жестко ограничить форматы загружаемых файлов через 'input'? Атрибут 'accept' только фильтрует, но дает возможность выбрать все форматы. Прочитал в гугле о написании различных скриптов на php или js. Может кто-то сталкивался с таким и имеет определенный опыт в этом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ограничения на стороне фронта всегда только для удобства пользователя. Их легко обойти. Если цель ограничений -- обеспечение корректной работы вашего приложения (сайта), то проверки надо делать на бэке.

Помните, что имя файла (расширение) ничего не говорит о его содержимом. В общем случае не позволяйте пользователям управлять именами файлов. Проверяйте то, что действительно важно. Например, если пользователь в качестве картинки загружает php-скрипт с расширением .png, то такая картинка просто не будет отображаться. А вот если он ухитриться загрузить её в папку, где выполняются php-скрипты вашего приложения, то он взломает сайт.

Для удобства пользователя достаточно добавить требования к файлу в интерфейс (например: "загрузите документ (doc, docx, pdf)") и отфильтровать файлы с помощью accept. Если вы переживаете, что пользователь затупит и загрузит что-то не то, то проверьте расширение имени файла. И не забывайте, что не надо ограничивать пользователя без действительно веской причины.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!